# select row from winforms listview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have listview which is populated with list of data. Now I want to select desired row and on click button to recognize that item to delete from a collection.

Question is how to recognize selected row from the listview?

```
private void buttonDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //selected data is of custom type MyData
    var selected = (MyData)....?
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should works

```
  private void buttonDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //selected data is of custom type MyData
        var selected = yourListView.SelectedItems.First();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

To add to @Zaphod's answer and make a little more robust:

```
private void buttonDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (yourListView.SelectedItems.Any())
    {
         //selected data is of custom type MyData
         var selected = yourListView.SelectedItems.First();
    }
}
```

You could use `.Count > 0` instead of `.Any()` and `.SelectedItems[0]` instead of `.First()`. Whatever you find more readable/maintainable.

Comment: Indeed. I even forgot the .Frst() in my answer.

Comment: Why I cannot convert selection item to my custom data type? var sel = (MyData)listView.SelectedItems[0];

Comment: Because .SelectedItems is a collection of ListViewItem. If you want to associate your custom data type with the listview item, you can use the Tag property. Then (MyData)listView.SelectedItems[0].Tag would give you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Old School answer :) without any LINQ statements

```
if(yourListView.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
{
  var item = yourListView.SelectedItems[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have to use casting for a deleting operation, just remove all the selected indices like this:

```
private void buttonDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    for (int i = listView1.SelectedIndices.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)                
         listView1.Items.RemoveAt(listView1.SelectedIndices[i]);
}
```

or more simply:

```
private void buttonDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    foreach(ListViewItem item in listView1.SelectedItems)                
         listView1.Items.Remove(item);
}
```

As you can see the item which is selected is of type `ListViewItem`, you can bind your data to this item via `Text` property (if the data is string) or `Tag` property. I don't understand what your `CustomData` is, is it a type inheriting `ListViewItem`?

Answer (score 0):

YOu should do this

```
  private void buttonDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {        

    if (yourListView.SelectedItems.Any())
   {
     //selected data is of custom type MyData
     var selected = (MyData)yourListView.SelectedItems[0];
    YourCollection.Remove(selected);
   }
  }
```